# Group Java log entries per servlet invocation

Tags: java, servlets, logging

In the application I'm currently working on, we have an in-house built logging setup where log messages from the business methods are buffered in a `ThreadLocal` variable. The actual logging is deferred until the end of the servlet invocation where there's a `Filter` that picks all messages up, concatenates them together, tags them with the information from the mapped diagnostic context and then saves them to a SQL database as a single log entry.

We want to get rid of this in-house logger because the code quality is not that good and it's getting a bit hard to maintain. Is the above use case possible to achieve with any publicly available Java logging framework? I looked around in Logback and Log4j documentation a bit but wasn't able to find anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash)

> Logstash is an open source, server-side data processing pipeline that
>   ingests data from a multitude of sources simultaneously, transforms
>   it, and then sends it to your favorite “stash.”

Answer (score 0):

We are doing something similar with log4j: we're having an engine that processes requests in the background and records log4j messages into a temporary file; at the end of the processing, if something was logged, the content of the temporary file is sent by e-mail.

To start recording to the temp file:

```
    String root = props
            .getProperty("gina.nas.log-capture.root", "gina.nas");
    String thresholdLogLevel = props.getProperty(
            "gina.nas.log-capture.threshold", "WARN");
    String fullLogLevel = props.getProperty("gina.nas.log-capture.level",
            "INFO");
    String pattern = props.getProperty("gina.nas.log-capture.pattern",
            "%d * %-5p * %m [%c]%n");
    includeFullLog = Boolean.parseBoolean(props.getProperty(
            "gina.nas.log-capture.full-log", "true"));
    this.layout = new PatternLayout(pattern);
    this.logger = root == null ? Logger.getRootLogger() : Logger
            .getLogger(root);

    // Threshold log
    this.thresholdLogFile = File.createTempFile("thcap", ".log");
    thresholdLogAppender = initWriterAppender(thresholdLogFile, layout,
                Level.toLevel(thresholdLogLevel));
    logger.addAppender(thresholdLogAppender);
```

To stop recording:

```
    logger.removeAppender(thresholdLogAppender);
    thresholdLogAppender.close();
    if (thresholdLogFile.isFile()) {
        if (sendMail && thresholdLogFile.length() > 0) {
            LOG.info("Error(s) detected, sending log by email...");
            MailService mail = new MailService(props);
            Map<String, Object> vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            vars.put("username", username);
            vars.put("taskid", taskID);
            vars.put("instance", instance);
            vars.put("exception", exception);
            vars.put("thresholdLogFile", getFileContent(thresholdLogFile));
            mail.sendMessage(LOGCAPTURE_TEMPLATE, null, null, vars);
        }
        thresholdLogFile.delete();
    }
```

Method initWriteAppender:

```
private WriterAppender initWriterAppender(File file, PatternLayout layout,
        Level level) throws IOException {
    OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    boolean ok = false;
    try {
        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(stream, "UTF-8");
        try {
            WriterAppender result = new WriterAppender(layout, writer);
            ok = true;
            result.setThreshold(level);
            return result;
        } finally {
            if (!ok) {
                writer.close();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (!ok) {
            stream.close();
        }
    }
}
```